# How to debug variable not posting to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to figure out how to debug an issue with the posting of a variable to my database. Everything is being posted, but the username. Any tips on how to debug this would be much  appreciated.

The username does run through a couple of functions first.  I'm not getting any errors with the script itself, but I'm also not getting anything to post to the database.

```
<?php

// Check to see there are posted variables coming into the script
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") die ("No Post Variables");
// Initialize the $req variable and add CMD key value pair
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
// Read the post from PayPal
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Now Post all of that back to PayPal's server using curl, and validate everything with PayPal
// We will use CURL instead of PHP for this for a more universally operable script (fsockopen has issues on some environments)
//$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$curl_result=$curl_err='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
$curl_err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$req = str_replace("&", "\n", $req);  // Make it a nice list in case we want to email it to ourselves for reporting

// Check that the result verifies
if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
    $req .= "\n\nPaypal Verified OK";
} else {
    $req .= "\n\nData NOT verified from Paypal!";
    mail(".com", "IPN interaction not verified", "$req", "From: .com" );
    exit();
}

/* CHECK THESE 4 THINGS BEFORE PROCESSING THE TRANSACTION, HANDLE THEM AS YOU WISH
1. Make sure that business email returned is your business email
2. Make sure that the transaction’s payment status is “completed”
3. Make sure there are no duplicate txn_id
4. Make sure the payment amount matches what you charge for items. (Defeat Price-Jacking) */

// Check Number 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
if ($receiver_email != ".com") {
    $message = "Investigate why and how receiver email is wrong. Email = " . $_POST['receiver_email'] . "\n\n\n$req";
    mail(".com", "Receiver Email is incorrect", $message, "From: .com" );
    exit(); // exit script
}
// Check number 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($_POST['payment_status'] != "Completed") {
    // Handle how you think you should if a payment is not complete yet, a few scenarios can cause a transaction to be incomplete
}
// Connect to database ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';
// Check number 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$this_txn = $_POST['txn_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM transactions WHERE txn_id='$this_txn' LIMIT 1");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($numRows > 0) {
    $message = "Duplicate transaction ID occured so we killed the IPN script. \n\n\n$req";
    mail(".com", "Duplicate txn_id in the IPN system", $message, "From: .com" );
    exit(); // exit script
} 
// Check number 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$product_id_string = $_POST['custom'];
$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); // remove last comma
// Explode the string, make it an array, then query all the prices out, add them up, and make sure they match the payment_gross amount
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string); // Uses Comma(,) as delimiter(break point)
$fullAmount = 0;
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {

    $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value); // Uses Hyphen(-) as delimiter to separate product ID from its quantity
    $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // Get the product ID
    $product_quantity = $id_quantity_pair[1]; // Get the quantity
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM products WHERE id='$product_id' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $product_price = $row["price"];
    }
    $product_price = $product_price * $product_quantity;
    $fullAmount = $fullAmount + $product_price;
}
$fullAmount = number_format($fullAmount, 2);
$grossAmount = $_POST['mc_gross']; 
if ($fullAmount != $grossAmount) {
        $message = "Possible Price Jack: " . $_POST['payment_gross'] . " != $fullAmount \n\n\n$req";
        mail(".com", "Price Jack or Bad Programming", $message, "From: .com" );
        exit(); // exit script
} 

//
//
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';

//now to always get unique username
$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));
if ( ! uniqueName($username))
{
    $username = makeUniqueName($username);
}


//function to check if is the existing username
function uniqueName($username)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM transactions WHERE username='$username'");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if ($numRows > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


//function to generate new unique username
function makeUniqueName($username)
{
    //serch username string for number at the end
    //regexp makes sure all preceeding zeroes go to first match group
    if (preg_match('/^(\S*?0*)?(\d+?)$/', $username, $match))
    {
        //we got digit from the end of string, just add 1 to the digit
        $username = $match[1] . ($match[2] + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        //no digit at the end of string, just add digit 1 at the end
        $username = $username . 1;
    }

if (uniqueName($username))
{
    return $username;
}

    return makeUniqueName($username);
}

// END ALL SECURITY CHECKS NOW IN THE DATABASE IT GOES ------------------------------------
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Homework - Examples of assigning local variables from the POST variables
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['payment_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$password = mt_rand(1000, 9999); 
$p_hash = md5($password);
$username = $_POST['username'];
 //

// Place the transaction into the database
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (product_id_array, payer_email, first_name, last_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee, password, ip, username) 
   VALUES('$custom','$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$payment_date','$mc_gross','$payment_currency','$txn_id','$receiver_email','$payment_type','$payment_status','$txn_type','$payer_status','$address_street','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country','$address_status','$notify_version','$verify_sign','$payer_id','$mc_currency','$mc_fee','$p_hash','$ip','$username')") or die ("unable to execute the query");
$to      = $payer_email;  
$subject = 'Learn  | Login Credentials';  
$message = ' 

Your officially all ready to go. To login use the information below.

Your account login information 
------------------------- 
Email: '.$payer_email.' 
Password: '.$password.' 
------------------------- 

You can now login at https://www..com/signin.php';  
$headers = 'From:noreply@.com' . "\r\n";  

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  
mysql_close();
// Mail yourself the details
mail(".com", "NORMAL IPN RESULT YAY MONEY!", $req, "From: ");

?>
```

Comment: Little bobby tables we call him... never ever directly insert post values into sql statements. read up on sql injection please!

Comment: @Gryphius
I was going to do something like this. A little off topic, but would that be the correct approach?

$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['username']);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Thanks! @Gryphius  I really appreciate that resource. Do you by chance have any tips for debugging the above?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$username`  before the `$sql = ...` line.  I think the problem is your `$username` is empty in the line `$username = $_POST['username']`.

Comment: `$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));`
and
`$username = $_POST['username'];`

which one is it? ;-)

Comment: @vinodadhikary if the page is fired off elsewhere and not as a single page how would you check the value. It's an IPN that runs when a viewer is at paypal and finalizes purchase.

Comment: @Gryphius is $username should be taking the value of emailaddress minus everything after @

Comment: @Chris, you could log them to a file.  Have a look at http://logging.apache.org/log4php/.  Another possibility is `$username = $_POST['user_name']` (this is based on the naming convention used for rest of the attributes).

Comment: exactly, then why do yout overwrite it from post variables? see my answer below

Comment: Using MD5 to hash passwords is not secure. Equivalent passwords can be calculated using [Rainbow Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Comment: @vinodadhikary that is not the issue. I'll take alook at that link. thanks

Comment: @Oswald I haven't quite run through the code for security just yet. My focus right now is on functionality then I'll go in through stackover flow previous posts to determine the best plan of attack. Thanks so much for your effort in keeping me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging involves:

1. Determining what the value of the variables during the script execution should be.
2. Determining what the value of the variables during the script execution actually are.
3. Determining the reason for a mismatch between the two.

This informatation can then be use to change the code so that actual and expected values of the variables match.

For item 1, an understanding of what the code should and how it should do it is necessary. The code itself is of little help at this point, because the code, failing to be able to read the programmers mind, does not know what is expected of it.

For item 2, you can place `print` statements in the code (and remove them after debugging). A better way is often to use a debugger like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/), preferably in combination with an IDE like [Eclipse PDT](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt).

As an example, I assume after

> ```
> $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (product_id_array, payer_email, first_name, last_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, txn_id, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee, password, ip, username)
> ```

the value of the `$sql` variable should be `true`. A `print($sql)` will confirm or refute this assumption. If it is `false`, a call to [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) will shed some light on the reason why the query failed. If it is `true` and a record with the expected username is not inserted, The value of `$username` is probably not what you expected.

Comment: Hi @Oswald thanks for the response. I look at it in the same way just don't quite understand how to debug .

Comment: I elaborated a bit. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:
Your $username variable seems to be generated based on the email first and running through various functions.

```
//now to always get unique username
$username = substr($payer_email, 0, strpos($payer_email, '@'));
if ( ! uniqueName($username))
{
    $username = makeUniqueName($username);
}
[...]
```

but at the end you overwrite it with:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

are you sure this field should be posted? maybe you just have to remove this line?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I've tried makeUniqueName and uniqueName but I'm just getting 1 2 ect. not the first part that includes the username created from payer_email

Comment: I'm not sure . I've tried both uniqueName and makeUniqueName but I'm just getting the values 1 or 2 ect. It doesn't include the username anymore. The username before was payer_email minus everything after the @ symbol.